# How much energy is my car using to carry it's spare wheel?

Tags: energy, friction

My car has a mass of around $M=1500kg$ and my spare wheel has a mass of around $m=20kg$.

My daily route covers a distance of around $d=100km$.

I checked online and seen that the coefficient of friction between the tyres and the road is around $\mu=0.3-0.7$ depending on surface conditions.

If that's true then I'd like to take a value of $\mu= 0.5$.

Taking $g=10ms^{-2}$.

My calculation is: $E_{Energy}=\mu m g d = 0.5*20*10*100000=10,000,000J$

$10MJ$ looks like an enormous amount to me.

What are people's thoughts on this?

I want to know how many joules are used to carry the spare wheel.

Comment: Is this a practical or homework question? If practical it'd be wiser to calculate the average SPEED( 100km divided by the time spent traveling in car) the car moves throughout the travel and then plug that speed into the kinetic energy equation and also search for average resistive forces and multiply with 100km and add the two energies to find your total for each with and without spare tire.

Comment: 1 gallon of gas holds 118MJ of useful energy, so your calculation may be correct! If you used a gallon of gas every day, the other 90% of energy could be spent by conversion efficiency losses (not everything from the engine is converted into force) and braking.

Answer (score 1):

You must not confuse rolling friction an gliding friction. The coefficient you gave is for gliding friction. What you effectively calculated is the energy you would need to slide your car along by pulling it while all breaks are locked.

In practice, the friction coefficient you gave is only relevant during emergency breaking. All (or most) other times the tire does not slide over the surface but remains in solid contact at the place of contact.

So, to summarize, use the correct coefficient for the rolling friction (which would have to include the gliding friction in the bearings) and you will find much less energy being dissipated from your spare wheel.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The frictional force is relevant only when some type of force tries to displace the wheel. (Think in terms of the acceleration of the car.)

For further clarification, let's consider two specific time intervals during the car's motion.

When the car is stationary, friction does no work on the wheel.

When the car is moving with some constant velocity, friction does no work on the wheel. (same thing)

When the car is *accelerating*, there is a perceived force on the wheel because of the inertia of the wheel. Friction counters this force to stop the wheel from sliding off. Hence, friction is only relevant when the car is accelerating, and this is what you need to consider.

I'm very sure that accounting for this will cut down your number by a huge amount.

Comment: Huh?  This is talking about a vehicle, not a block.  I think I get where you are going with this, but it honestly seems really unclear for a hint.

Comment: I don't see why you're confused? Is it better now?